# Alert Message not called in iOS app when push notification is received

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase

I tried many things, however I think the problem is that I don't know what gets called first when a Push Notification is received. If I knew that it would solve my problem. I 'think' the following class gets called first:

```
class UserNotifications: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
```

Then, does the appDelegate get called? Or... the other way around?

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials available on how to receive a push notification. Try a google search

Comment: yes did look through them, but it did not explain what gets called first.

Comment: The question is pretty unclear. Are you asking if a push notification 'calls the app delegate' or calls a function *within the app delegate* that handles the notification?